# C & Nasm64 combination - stack alignment, epilogue, prologue - OSX 64

Tags: c, macos, nasm

The following program causing a segmentation fault and I don't seem to understand why:

```
//something.c



int somefunc3();
void somefunc2();

void* globalptr;

void somefunc1(void* regs)
{
    globalptr = regs;   
    somefunc2();
}

int foo() 
{

    return somefunc3();
}


int main(void)
{
    show_all_registers();
    foo();
    show_all_registers();
}
```

asm:

```
//something1.asm

extern _somefunc1

global _somefunc2
global _somefunc3

section .text


%macro RESTORE_REGISTERS 0
    pop rcx
    pop rcx
    pop rcx
    pop rcx
    pop rcx
    pop rcx
    pop rcx
    pop rcx 
    pop rcx
    pop rcx
    pop rcx
    pop rcx
    pop rcx
    pop rcx
    pop rcx
    pop rcx
%endmacro

%macro SAVE_REGISTERS 0
    push rcx
    push rcx
    push rcx
    push rcx
    push rcx
    push rcx
    push rcx
    push rcx       
    push rcx
    push rcx
    push rcx
    push rcx    
    push rcx
    push rcx
    push rcx
    push rcx
%endmacro

_somefunc3:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    SAVE_REGISTERS
    mov rdi, rsp

    sub rsp,8
    call    _somefunc1
    add rsp,8

    pop rbp
    ret

_somefunc2:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    RESTORE_REGISTERS
    pop rbp
ret
```

few notes:

- Please don't try to understand what this program does because you won't find anything that makes sense. This is just a user mode app which I created in order to understand something.
- show_all_registers is just a function that prints out to the screen all of the 64 bit registers.

Here's what happens before it crashes:

```
64 Bit registers:
RAX=10767ad00, RCX=1, RDX=10767ab70, RBX=0, RSP=7fff58585bd0, RBP=7fff58585bd0, RSI=20000000200,     RDI=7
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Using GDB it seems that the crash occurs on somefunc2 (When restoring the registers)

I think that it has something to do with stack alignment or the epilogues & epilogues I wrote for the ASM functions. Still kinda newbie so it is most likely something silly.

thanks

Comment: You're using GDB, you should be able to figure out exactly what is going wrong.  Which specific instruction does GDB show is the source of the SIGSEGV?

Comment: the return operation of somefunc2. seems that the address that it should return to isn't valid or just not placed correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function epilogues are incorrect.  You're missing the `mov rsp, rbp`, so your stack frame is totally off at return time.

A proper function would be:

```
push rbp
mov  rbp, rsp
sub  rsp, [size of local variables]
...
mov  rsp, rbp
pop  rbp
ret
```

Or you can simplify with the `LEAVE` instruction:

```
push rbp
mov  rbp, rsp
sub  rsp, [size of local variables]
...
leave
ret
```